# Rebase a branch from another branch that is rebased from master

Tags: git, rebase

I have this scenario:

```
o---o---o---o---o  master
     \
      o---o---o---o---o  next
                       \
                        o---o---o  topic
```

As above, I did some commits on master and I want to update the other two branches and have:

```
o---o  master
     \
      o---o---o---o---o  next
                       \
                        o---o---o  topic
```

I already did the `git rebase master` on `next` branch, without thinking about that `topic` now hasn't the base commit of `next` branch.

What could I do now? Was I wrong to rebase immediately the intermediate branch? What should I do?

Comment: I do `git checkout topic; git rebase next` but wonder if there is better solution. Sometimes I need to resolve thing I feel should be avoidable

Comment: I already tried that, but git can't rebase because `topic` hasn't anymore the base commit of `next, that is changed by the rebase master. It's hard to explain what I want to say, I hope is clear! :D

Comment: Not clear. I do exactly this kind of rebase sometimes and while not ideal it works for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two relatively easy solutions to this problem.  One is to just try the rebase, which might just work.  But if not, it's still easy.  Here's the second, more powerful way, followed by *why*:

```
git checkout topic; git rebase --onto next next@{1}
```

#### What's going on: how rebase works

The view is, I think, much clearer if you draw the graph a bit differently.  Here's the original, redrawn slightly:

```
A---B---C---D---E                   <-- master
     \
      F---G---H---I---J             <-- next
                       \
                        K---L---M   <-- topic
```

Here's what you have after `git checkout next; git rebase master`:

```
A---B---C---D---E                   <-- master
     \           \
     |            F'-G'-H'-I'-J'    <-- next
     \
      F---G---H---I---J             [was "next", but not anymore]
                       \
                        K---L---M   <-- topic
```

This is because rebase works by *copying* commits, with some slight (or major) change(s).  New commit `F'` is a copy of original `F`, `G'` is a copy of `G`, and so  on.

If you now run `git checkout topic; git rebase next`, it *usually* just works—but not always.  The reason for this is that, by default, `rebase` chooses *which commits to copy* and *where to copy-after* from a single argument.  This gets a bit complicated, so let's take this in two steps.

When you say `git rebase next` here, the single argument is `next`: the copies will go after the tip commit of `next` (which is now `J'`).  This part is totally straightforward: that one identifier, `next`, finds the commit `--onto` which the copies are appended.  (There's a reason I spelled this `--onto` instead of just "onto". :-) )

The *what gets copied* part is trickier, in two ways.  First, `next` specifies what *not* to copy, while the current branch (`topic`) specifies what *to* copy.  Git gets a list of all commits reachable from `topic`—which is commits `A`, `B`, `F`, `G`, `H`, and so on all the way through `L`.  Then it *excludes* all commits reachable from `next`, which is commits `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F'` (but not `F`), `G'` (but not `G`), and so on through `J'`.  It doesn't matter that some excluded commits are not in the included list: we just exclude those that *are* in the included list.

Unfortunately, this leaves commits `F`, `G`, `H`, `I`, and `J` in the pile of commits-to-be-copied.  This is where, as you noticed, things go wrong.  But somehow, *most of the time*, this works anyway.  What's going on when it works?  And why doesn't it *always* work?

The answer is that rebase *also* excludes "patch-equivalent commits".  The general idea here is that when you're rebasing, Git scans through the "exclude" list to see if any of those commits *do the same thing* as a commit in the "include" list.  Since `F'` is a copy of `F`, it's likely to be "the same" as `F`, at least in a patch-equivalence sense.  The same goes for `G` vs `G'`, `H` vs `H'`, and so on.

***As long as the commits are patch-identical to their rebased versions, they get excluded.***

When this is true—and it usually is—you can simply `git checkout topic; git rebase next` and it just works.  It's when it's *not* true—when some of `F` through `H` got modified "too much" while being copied, and their copies are no longer patch-equivalent—that it fails.

As a sort of rule of thumb,<sup>1</sup> if Git is able to do the first rebase all by itself, it will be able to do the second all by itself too.  It's mainly when it stops with a conflict, and makes you fix it by hand, that the patches become "not-patch-equivalent".  But it's easy enough to deal with this, because `git rebase` has a longer form.

Instead of:

```
git rebase next
```

we can write:

```
git rebase --onto next <something>
```

Based on the graph we drew, the `<something>` to use here is *anything that specifies commit `J`*.  That is, we need to find where `next` *was*.  What commit did `next` point to, *before* we rebased it?  It now points to `J'` but it used to point to `J`.  The commits we need Git to exclude are those that `next` *used to* reach: `A`, `B`, `F`, `G`, `H`, `I`, and `J`.  If Git can't find these on its own, via patch-equivalence, we can just *tell* it.

That still leaves the question of how to spell a name that identifies commit `J`.  One way is by raw hash ID, which always works, but is a bit of a pain (both to find, and to copy, though cut-and-paste works pretty well for copying hashes).  But look at the redrawn graph again, with the bit that says `was "next", but not anymore`.  If only we could tell Git to look up the *previous* value of `next`.

But wait!  Git has *reflogs*!  We *can* tell it to do just that!  The previous value of `next` is spelled `next@{1}`.  (The number increments every time we change the label `next`, by adding a new commit to it for instance, but all we've done just now is the one `rebase`, so it's still `next@{1}`.)  So at this point we can just do this:

```
git checkout topic; git rebase --onto next next@{1}
```

(depending on your shell, you might need to use quotes around something with braces in it, e.g., `'next@{1}'` or `next@\{1\}` or some such).

---

<sup>1</sup>There are some exceptions.  For instance, in this case, if `git diff E F'` doesn't produce the same change-set as `git diff B F` due to diff picking up different semi-irrelevant matches, like blank lines or close-brace lines, that would cause a problem.  However, the answer to dealing with these is the same as the answer to dealing with hand-applied rebases due to conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for this complete explanation! Anyway, I fixed by rebasing interactively and leaving only the topic's branch, but I understand what you explained me and I'll keep in mind it for the next time! :) Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, interactive rebase is another way to deal with this, since you get a chance to delete the already-copied commits. Another is to write a program that does a multi-branch rebase "all at once" by figuring out the shared and unique portions. When all branch labels are contained within one "main" rebase (as in this case) you just do the main rebase and then move all the interior labels.

Comment: Thank you @torek for the excellent answer! I would upvote twice if I could :) Worked like a charm. What I did was an interactive rebase with `next`, where I squashed some commits (`git checkout next; git rebase -i HEAD~8`). Then I switched to `topic` and wanted to rebase onto the new commits from `next` (`git checkout topic; git rebase next`). But (thanks to your explanation), I understand now that the squashed commits were not patch-equivalent anymore. So I did the `git rebase --onto next next@{1}` and my history is clean now.